# Create static instead of a temporary for a function parameter

Tags: c++

I'm looking for a bit of C++ syntax sugar here, if there's a way to do this.  I have a class which maps a string to an int, and defines an int cast operator:

```
class C {
    public:
        C(const char * s) { m_index = /* value generated from s */; }
        operator int(void) const { return m_index; }
    protected:
        int m_index;
}
```

If I do the following:

```
void foo(int f);
...
static const C s_c("TEST");
foo(s_c);
```

The compiler invokes the constructor for C exactly once and reuses the int value obtained in every subsequent use of s_c; this is desirable behavior.  My question is, is there some way to do:

```
foo(C("TEST"));
```

and have the compiler make a static, as above, rather than making a temporary and hitting the constructor every time the code is hit?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is there a particular reason you absolutely must not write this on 2 lines?

Comment: This sounds like it might be an XY problem.
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Maybe a proposal to the C++ committee. However, I can't think of a viable way of doing it.

Comment: The problem I'm trying to solve is making code that utilizes this string->int mapping, is readable, and performs optimally.  I could make an enum that maps 1:1 with the strings, but then I have to separately maintain the enum and the strings.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use C++11, you can use `constexpr` to do transformations on literals:

```
// shamelessly copy-pasted from elsewhere
constexpr int some_hash(char const *in) {
  return *in ? static_cast<int>(*in) + 33 * some_hash(in + 1) : 5381;
}
```

Note that you have some pretty hefty restrictions though: no temporaries or statics, no access to outside variable, etc.

Comment: Thank you - unfortunately, my code would be updating tables in global memory.

Comment: can you separate the `int` generation from the global table updates? you can still buy some easy gains if so.  If what you're looking for is to maintain terse usage syntax, you're out of luck. `foo(C("TEST"))` will always tell the compiler to call `foo()` on a temporary `C`, and there is absolutely no way around that, since the language's first responsibility is to maintain its own consistent semantics.

Comment: Thank you again Jeff, yea this option is unfortunately not available to me - I'm thinking the answer to my question might be "no".

Comment: there are less direct approximations of what you might want, Benny. Is your `m_index` calculation a pure mapping, or does it rely on the dynamic state of other transformed strings?

Comment: It is pure in the sense that same input gives you same output, but the first time you do the lookup, there are table modifications and things like that - in subsequent calls, nothing is modified.

Comment: You could consider making `foo` a template function if it would fit your use case needs: `template <int HashVal> void foo();` and calls like `foo<some_hash("TEST")>();`, where `foo` is now a wrapper to your old underlying implementation touching dynamic state.